# JWT with Firebase php-jwt

Tags: php, jwt

So my web app requires JWT authentication and I decided to make a mockup wrapper class for php-jwt before implementing it into my web app:

```
class JWTWrapper{
    public function newToken($issuedAt, $notBefore, $expire, $server, $sessionData){
        $tokenId = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(32));
        $notBefore = $notBefore + $issuedAt;
        $expire = $expire + $notBefore;
        $data = [
            'iat' => $issuedAt,
            'jti' => $tokenId,
            'iss' => $server,
            'nbf' => $notBefore,
            'exp' => $expire,
            'data' => $sessionData
        ];

        $jwt = JWT::encode($data, PRIVATE_KEY, "HS512");

        return $jwt;
    }

    public function getToken($jwt){
        if($jwt){
            try{
                $token = JWT::decode($jwt, PRIVATE_KEY, ["HS512"]);
                return $token;
            } catch(Exception $e){
                return false;
            }
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getTokenData($jwt){
        if($jwt){
            try{
                $token = JWT::decode($jwt, PRIVATE_KEY, ["HS512"]);
                return $token->data;
            } catch(Exception $e){
                return false;
            }
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I've been reading over articles about JWT vulnerabilities such as so im really paranoid I might have made some sort of catastrophic mistake like [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/03/31/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/) (even though its not apparent that I have...)